# Google App Engine local Datastore after SDK upgrade

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have just upgraded to SDK 1.7.7 and my application can no longer access the local data store. I've Googled a bit and found that this usually occurs when upgrading the SDK.

I can't seem to find any solution that will allow me keep my existing data. I have set up a ton of test data in my datastore that I don't want to have to re-create. Is there ANY way to transition/migrate the data in the local datastore from one SDK version to another?

Answer (score 1):

The steps I use are:

1) make a remote_api connection  https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api

something like

```
    static RemoteApiOptions options;
    options = new RemoteApiOptions().server("localhost", 8888).credentials("", ""); // password doesn't matter

    RemoteApiInstaller installer = new RemoteApiInstaller();
    installer.install(options);
```

2) fetch my data (this is for me with Objectify, but it'd be how you'd normally do it)

```
            UserDAO udao = new UserDAO(false);
            Query<UserOFY> qu = udao.ofy().query(UserOFY.class);
```

3) persist my data to the harddrive

something like

```
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(LOCAL_AE_BACKUPS_USER + "/" + USERS_FROM_LOCAL_BACKUP + "_" + u.getNickName());
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(u);
            out.close();
```

then I just do the reverse after upgrading the version.

1) read the persisted data on my hard drive

2) make a connection to the local datastore

3) persist the data to the new version of the local datastore